Weighted bipartite matching with no-cycle constraint
Given a weighted bipartite graph, I need to find a maximum-weight matching with the following additional constraint: the residual graph of the chosen matching is not allowed to contain any cycles. By residual graph, I mean the graph consisting of:

all edges that are not part of the matching, directed from left to right;
all edges that are part of the matching, directed from right to left.

For example, consider the graph with left vertices ${a,b,c}$ and right vertices ${A,B,C}$, where the edges and weights are

$(a,B): 6$
$(a,C): 10$
$(b,A): 15$
$(b,C): 10$
$(c,A): 15$
$(c,B): 6.$


One possible optimal matching is $(a,C)$ and $(b,A)$ with value $25$. The residual graph (with these edges reversed, in red) is illustrated above. Augmenting this matching with $(c,B)$ is not possible since reversing the direction of the $(c,B)$ edge would create a cycle $a\rightarrow B\rightarrow c\rightarrow A\rightarrow b\rightarrow C\rightarrow a$ in the residual graph.
Is there an algorithm for finding such a matching?

@D.W. I've added the definition and a picture above. I mean "residual graph" in the sense of graph you get as you push flow through the graph from left to right, if you interpret the matching problem as maximum-cost max flow.

Claim: A matching $M$ has a cycle-free residual graph if and only if the graph $G[V(M)]$ induced on its vertex set has a unique perfect matching.
Given this, the problem is at least as hard as 2-approximation Directed Feedback Vertex Set. Let $D=(V,A)$ be a directed graph and let $G$ be the bipartite graph where every vertex $v_i \in V$ maps to two vertices $u_i, v_i$ in $G$, and $(u_i,v_j)$ is an arc in $G$ if and only if $(v_i,v_j)$ is an arc in $D$ or if $i=j$. Then $G$ has precisely one perfect matching if and only if $D$ is acyclic.
That is, if $S$ is a DFVS of $D$ then deleting both copies of $S$ in $G$ yields a graph with a unique perfect matching, and if $M$ is a matching in $G$ with acyclic residual graph then deleting in $D$ every vertex that does not have both copies in $V(M)$ yields a DFVS for $G$.
Since it is UGC-hard to find a constant-factor approximation for DFVS (reference: Wikipedia), finding a maximum-cardinality matching $M$ of your type is at least UGC-hard.

A more direct answer: this problem is NP-hard.
Reduce from Independent set:
$G = (V,E)$ an undirected graph with $V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$.
Build the bipartite graph $B$ whose vertices are $v_1, \ldots, v_n, v'_1, \ldots, v'_n$.
Each $v_i$ is connected to $v_i'$ by an edge with weight 1 and for all $i \neq j$, $v_i$ is connected to $v'_j$ by an edge of weight 0 if and only if $\{v_i, v_j\} \in E$ (otherwise they are not connected).
The second set of edges ensures that we never select both $\{v_i, v_i'\}$ and $\{v_j, v_j'\}$ when $v_i, v_j$ are neighbours in $G$, as this would create a cycle $v_1-v_i'-v_j-v_j'-v_i$.
It is then straightforward to prove that a matching of weight $k$ in $B$ comes down to finding an independent set with $k$ elements in $G$.
The problem of checking if there is a matching satisfying your requirements and of weight larger than a given $k$ is thus NP-hard. As a consequence, there is no polynomial-time algorithm for your problem unless P=NP.
